# when slow query ran on slave does it logs in master slow query log also

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-slow-query-log

I have Master and slave replication using Maria DB
I connected to slave DB and executed a query which is a slow query, but that slow query logged in both master and slave slow query logs

Answer (score 1):

No.  The Master and the Slave(s) each have a slowlog (if turned on).  They record only slow queries from the same machine.

Furthermore, queries that are replicated will not show up in the Slave slowlog unless you turn ON `log_slow_slave_statements`.  I recommend doing this.

I also recommend turning OFF `log_queries_not_using_indexes`; it clutters the slowlog while providing only minimal useful info.

The default `long_query_time = 10` leaves the slowlog virtually useless; crank that down to 2 or 1.

For help with slow queries, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog